# Insert a special character into a pattern using Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a pattern - something like this:

```
word1|some stuff word2|some stuff word3|some stuff
```

I would like to add the `@` character before a word followed by pipe (words before a pipe are different) - to get something like this:

```
@word1|some stuff, @word2|some stuff @word3|some stuff
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have to use regex? Why not simply use a string replace function?

Comment: I do not know the word before pipe, it could be anything

Comment: Replacing only the pipe is not an option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
$str = "word1|some stuff word2|some stuff word3|some stuff"; 

$result = preg_replace('/(\w+\|)/', '@$1', $str);
//=> @word1|some stuff @word2|some stuff @word3|some stuff
```

#### [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oK0iG6/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~\w+\|~', '@$0', $yourstring);
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/fS8mF0/7), look at the substitutions at the bottom.

**Explanation**

- `\w+` matches word characters
- `\|` matches the pipe
- `@$0` replaces the match with `@` then the overall match `$0`